# Tiny MCE anchor link not clickable

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have Tiny MCE editor plugin installed in my site, but now I am facing one strange issue there.I inserted one link in editor, but that link is not clickable from editor, I need to right click on link text and click on Open in new tab.

Any help?

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Comment: can you guide as to a live example? it is difficult to analize anything without

Comment: Go inside editor, add/edit link enter URL, Text and Select New Window tab and Click on Save.Then after in Editor you will see the text highlighted as link, clicking on that will not work, But instead you will need to right click and open in new tab